# Defining function with several bindings in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Consider the following simplified lambda-calculus with the peculiarity that bound variables can occur on the bound type:

```
theory Example
  imports "Nominal2.Nominal2" 
begin


atom_decl vrs

nominal_datatype ty = 
    Top

nominal_datatype trm = 
    Var   "vrs"
  | Abs   x::"vrs" t::"trm" T::"ty" binds x in t T

nominal_function
  fv :: "trm ⇒ vrs set"
where
  "fv (Var x) = {x}"
| "fv (Abs x t T) = (fv t) - {x}"
  using [[simproc del: alpha_lst]]  
  subgoal by(simp add: fv_graph_aux_def eqvt_def eqvt_at_def)
  subgoal by simp
  subgoal for P x
    apply(rule trm.strong_exhaust[of x P]) 
    by( simp_all add: fresh_star_def fresh_Pair)
                apply simp_all
  subgoal for x T t xa Ta ta  
    sorry

end
```

I have been unable to show the last goal:

> eqvt_at fv_sumC T ⟹ eqvt_at fv_sumC Ta ⟹ 
>   [[atom x]]lst. (T, t) = [[atom xa]]lst. (Ta, ta) ⟹ 
>   fv_sumC T - {x} = fv_sumC Ta - {xa}

despite my efforts of a day.

**Solution**

```
subgoal for x T t xa Ta ta  
  proof -
    assume 1: "[[atom x]]lst. (t, T) = [[atom xa]]lst. (ta, Ta)"
          " eqvt_at fv_sumC t" " eqvt_at fv_sumC ta"
    then have 2: "[[atom x]]lst. t = [[atom xa]]lst. ta"
      by(auto simp add: Abs1_eq_iff'(3) fresh_Pair)      
    show "removeAll x (fv_sumC t) = removeAll xa (fv_sumC ta)"
      apply(rule Abs_lst1_fcb2'[OF 2, of _ "[]"])
         apply (simp add: fresh_removeAll)
        apply (simp add: fresh_star_list(3))
      using 1 Abs_lst1_fcb2' unfolding eqvt_at_def
      by auto
  qed
```

Comment: @user9716869 i would like to drop supp ty from fv_trm Abs case to match my definition. I'm aware of the theory but nominal 2 has no supporting documentation (or so I think so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad that you were able to work out the solution. Nonetheless, I would still like to elaborate on the comment that I previously made. In particular, I would like to emphasize that `nominal_datatype` already provides a very similar function automatically: it is the function `fv_trm`. This function is, effectively, equivalent to the function `fv` in your question. Here is a rough sketch (the proof will need to be refined) of a theory that demonstrates this:

```
theory Scratch
  imports "Nominal2.Nominal2"
begin

atom_decl vrs

nominal_datatype ty = 
  Top

nominal_datatype trm = 
    Var vrs
  | Abs x::vrs t::trm T::ty binds x in t T

lemma supp_ty: "supp (ty::ty) = {}"
  by (metis (full_types) ty.strong_exhaust ty.supp)

lemmas fv_trm = trm.fv_defs[unfolded supp_ty supp_at_base, simplified]

lemma dom_fv_trm: 
  "a ∈ fv_trm x ⟹ a ∈ {a. sort_of a = Sort ''Scratch.vrs'' []}"
  apply(induction rule: trm.induct)
  unfolding fv_trm 
  by auto

lemma inj_on_Abs_vrs: "inj_on Abs_vrs (fv_trm x)"
  using dom_fv_trm by (simp add: Abs_vrs_inject inj_on_def)

definition fv where "fv x = Abs_vrs ` fv_trm x"

lemma fv_Var: "fv (Var x) = {x}"
  unfolding fv_def fv_trm using Rep_vrs_inverse atom_vrs_def by auto

(*I leave it to you to work out the details, 
but Sledgehammer already finds something sensible*)
lemma fv_Abs: "fv (Abs x t T) = fv t - {x}"
  using inj_on_Abs_vrs
  unfolding fv_def fv_trm 
  sorry

end
```

Comment: @Rodrigo I suggest that you post your solution as an answer and accept it. It is a better answer for the question, as the question is stated. Nonetheless, of course, in my view, it is nearly always best to reuse the functions generated automatically as much as you can. As for your comment on the theory, I am not aware of the existence of the documentation for Nominal2. However, it seems, most theoretical concepts can be transferred from Nominal to Nominal2 almost directly (modulo the notation). Still, I only used Nominal2 very briefly, so I might be wrong.